# Finding a equation for a tangent line to the curve $y=e^x$ which also goes through the origin

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function, tangent-line

I have an assignment

> Find an equation for a tangent line to the curve $y=e^x$ which also goes through the origin.

However, in my formula it is asserted 
that the slope between at a point "p" and the origin is

$m=\frac{e^p-0}{p-o}$ = $\frac{d}{dx}e^x$ **(at $x=p$)** = $e^p$

but surely $\frac{e^p-0}{p-o} = \frac{e^p}{p}$ how is this equal to

$\frac{d}{dx}e^x$ **(at $x=p$)** = $e^p$?

Am I missing something obvious?

Thank you in advance

Comment: what do you mean with a line to the curve?

Comment: Yes. my apologies

Comment: That’s the crux of the problem: finding a $p$ such that $e^p=e^p/p$.

Comment: amd's comment should be enough ? ... but if you want an even bigger hint https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nq6sneqgjn

Comment: @amd I see why. Your answer was very helpful, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

If you mean the tangent line to the graph then let $(a,e^a)$ be a common point.

Thus, $$y-e^a=e^a(x-a)$$ and since our tangent line goes through the origin,
we obtain
$$0-e^a=e^a(0-a),$$ which gives $a=1$ and the answer: $y=ex$.

Answer (score 1):

The troublesome equal sign isn't a conclusion, it's a condition.  The slope of the line is expressed in two different ways.  $m = \frac{e^p}{p}$ by algebra methods and $m=e^p$ by calculus methods.  They are set equal to each other so that you can solve for $p$:

$$\frac{e^p}{p} = e^p$$

$$\frac{1}{p} = 1$$

$$p=1$$

So the slope of the tangent line you're seeking is $e^1$.  Its $y$-intercept is $0$, so the equation is $y=ex$.

Comment: So the issue with finding a equation using y=m(x-x_{1})+y_{1}
is that for the alegebraic $m=\frac{e^p}{p}$ "p" is unknown? But essentially if a line has to pass through (0,0) aswell as it has to be tangent to $e^x$, p has to be 1, if I understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes, $p$ has to be $1$.  The equation forces that.

Comment: It makes perfectly sense now, Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Problem:

> Find an equation for a tangent line to the curve $y=e^{x}$ which also goes through the origin.

Here's how I would solve it:

For a line to be tangent to a given curve, the line and the curve must share a common point. Let's call it $(x_{0},e^{x_{0}})$. Then, the slope of the line tangent to the curve $y=e^{x}$ at $x_{0}$ must be: $\frac{d}{dx}e^{x}|_{x=x_{0}}=e^{x_{0}}$. From that we can fine the line equation of the sought tangent line in terms of the point $x_{0}$:

$$
y-e^{x_{0}}=e^{x_{0}}(x-x_{0})\implies
y=e^{x_{0}}x-e^{x_{0}}(x_{0}-1)
$$

According to the problem statement, the line should also go through the origin:

$$
0=e^{x_{0}}\cdot 0-e^{x_{0}}(x_{0}-1)\implies x_{0}=1\\
$$

Now, just plug in $x_{0}=1$ into our original equation:

$$
y=e^{1}x-e^{1}(1-1)\implies y=ex
$$

Answer: $y=ex$.